# Use NSString data to rotate UIImage layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, nsstring

I have an NSString that has a variable data range of 0-1024

```
//Convert the incoming data into a string 
NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I am then using an NSScanner to convert the string to an integerValue

```
NSString *numberString;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:msg];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:NULL];

[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&numberString];

int number = [numberString integerValue];
```

I then convert this to a Float:

```
msgFloat = [numberString intValue];
NSLog(@"Float Val is: %f", msgFloat);
```

**The NSLog DOES show the value of "msgFloat" correctly.**

Now I want to use this "msgFloat" as my "value (0-1024)" to rotate a UIImage Layer on a round gauge.

```
self.speedometerCurrentValue = msgFloat;

self.speedometerReading.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",self.speedometerCurrentValue];

// Calculate the Angle by which the needle should rotate //
[self calculateDeviationAngle];

//Redraw needle.
[needleImageView setNeedsDisplay];
```

The "msgFloat" value is being reported correctly in a UITextField in the app but is not rotating the UIImage.  However, if I manually type  a value from 0-1024 (see the commented out line below) then that moves the image on to the correct position on the gauge.

```
//self.speedometerCurrentValue = 1024.000000;
```

I hope I asked this question clearly.  I am wondering why I can manually locate the UIImage layer but I can't do it from my NSString value that is always changing?

Comment: Is `msgFloat` actually typed as `float`? If not, I'll bet you're doing some division whose result is being truncated. But there's no way to tell from this. What happens in `calculateDeviationAngle`? Also, look at `-[NSScanner scanInt:]`.

Comment: Hi Josh!  In reference to your first question "Is msgFloat actually typed as float?" do you mean is it typed as float in this line(from above)- "self.speedometerCurrentValue = msgFloat;"  Because I DO feel like this is the line that is wrong.  Do I have to use different language other than just "msgFloat"?  I think its interesting that I can type a value like "512" instead of "msgFloat" and the needle rotates to exactly where it should.

Comment: msgFloat = [numberString intValue]; <-- this should be [numberString floatValue]; no?

Comment: Sorry, actually it's probably `speedometerCurrentValue` that's important. Is it `@property (...) float speedometerCurrentValue;`? `double` works instead of `float`, too. But again, that's depending on what's going on inside `calculateDeviationAngle`.